# How to apply css on every 2nd child using nth-child() with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Hi i want to apply style on every 2nd `<li>`

i have tried

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cl li:nth-child(2)').css('color', 'red');    
})
</script>
```

Html

```
<ul id="cl">
  <li>home</li>
  <li>home2</li>
  <li>home3</li>
  <li>home4</li>
  <li>home5</li>
  <li>home6</li>
</ul>
```

i can apply style on only 2nd child by using this code . how can i apply style on every second child

Thanks in advance
:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `:odd` selector:

```
$('#cl li:odd').css('color', 'red');
```

http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Here's Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uKX3t/1/

The reason you need to use `:odd` as opposed to `:even` is because the children is 0-indexed, meaning that `<li>home</li>` is the 0th child and `<li>home2</li>` is the first child which is odd.

Quote from the docs:

> In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that,
>   counter-intuitively, :odd selects the second element, fourth element,
>   and so on within the matched set.

So oddly, you need to use `odd` selector (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead -

```
$('#cl li:odd').css('color', 'red');
```